# jpa save method return null result

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Here is my code.

```
CaseDetail resultCase = caseRepository.save(updateCase);
if (resultCase == null) { 
      throw new BaseException("Failed to update!");
}
```

When I call the save method to update the existed case, and then it returns null. So strange.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show the method  `.save` code.

Comment: FYI The JPA API has no such "save" method. You are using Spring Data JPA which is a TOTALLY DIFFERENT API